# pi/4 QPSK modulation/demodulation in GNU Radio

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio

Is there any quick mechanism to create pi/4 QPSK or pi/2 BPSK modulation scheme in GNU Radio using Constellation Modulator object or Constellation Object? Or I need to write it by myself? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use chunks to symbols to convert your data to PSK symbols, and a vector source to alternatively generate $0, \Delta \varphi$. Multiply the two streams, then do pulse shaping.